How to preserve links when copying text from an HTML element with JS
I'm trying to copy rich text where the links from HTML elements are preserved but I can't figure it out no matter how many times I try.
The code below is the best I can come up with, but it only copies text without preserving the links
const tempElem: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement("div");
tempElem.innerHTML = responseBody;

console.log("running clipboard.write()....");

try {
  navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
      "text/html": new Blob([tempElem.innerText], {
        type: "text/html",
      }),
      "text/plain": new Blob([tempElem.innerText], {
        type: "text/plain",
      }),
    }),
  ])

  console.log("Rich text copied to clipboard");
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Failed to copy: ", err);
}


Have you perhaps tried using innerHTML instead of innerText?

innerHTML would indeed solve the issue. @RoryMcCrossan would you like to share the answer?

@NijatMursali If that does indeed solve OPs problem, then it makes more sense to close this as a typographical issue. Rich text copying has most likely covered in lots of other questions.

@RoryMcCrossan correct. OP, please let us know if it solves the issue, or I might share the snippet I created now.

@RoryMcCrossan, thanks for commenting.
I have tried doing innerHTML but what it does is copy the all the html elements' syntax. I need just the text but with links preserved.
you know how when you copy text from a website with links and paste it on an email client as the body of an email. it preserves the links

With .innerText you get the rendered text of the element.  For a link like <a href="https://example.com/">example</a> you get the text "example". The information that it was a link is lost. With .innerHTML you still get text but with all tags and formating. If that is too much information, you might want to filter what to copy.

actually, you guys are are right. I tried it a again. and .innerHTML is the correct answer. It was my testing tool running in a VDI that made it into an html string. thanks everyone


With .innerText you get the rendered text of the element. For a link like <a href="https://example.com/">example</a> you get the text "example". The information that it was a link is lost.
With .innerHTML you still get text but with all tags and formating. If that is too much information, you might want to filter what to copy.

Below you find an example of how to filter the element, by making a new element with children, and copy only selected attributes. Some tags, like SCRIPT and STYLE are removed, and all comments too.


function nodeFilter(input, opt) {
  // An array of elelemnts to remove.
  const tagsRemove = opt?.tagsRemove || ['SCRIPT', 'STYLE'];
  // A Map of attributes to copy for each element.
  const attrCopy = opt?.attrCopy || new Map([
    ['A', ['href']]
  ]);

  const cloneChildren = (dst, src) => {
    for (const child of src.childNodes) {
      const childNew = filter(child);
      if (childNew) dst.append(childNew);
    }
    return dst;
  };

  const filter = (node) => {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        {
          const tagName = node.tagName;

          if (~tagsRemove.indexOf(tagName)) return null;

          const nodeNew = document.createElement(tagName);

          // Get a list of attributes to copy.
          const attrList = []
            .concat(
              attrCopy.get('*'), // wildcard
              attrCopy.get(tagName)
            )
            .filter((a) => a);

          // Copy attributes in list
          for (const attrName of attrList) {
            nodeNew.setAttribute(attrName, node.getAttribute(attrName));
          }

          return cloneChildren(nodeNew, node);
        }
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        // Clone text nodes
        return node.cloneNode();
      case Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE:
        // clone children of a document fragment
        return cloneChildren(document.createDocumentFragment(), node);
      case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
        return null;
      case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
        return null;
      case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
        // remove comments
        return null;
      case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:
        // remove processing instructions
        return null;
      case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
        // remove the document type
        return null;
      case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
        // clone children of a document
        return cloneChildren(new Document(), node);
      default:
        // remove unknown node types
        console.warn('Unknown nodeType', node.nodeType, 'ignored');
        return null;
    }
  };

  return filter(input);
}



document.getElementById('btnCopy').addEventListener(
  'click', (event) => {
    try {
      // Get the element
      const elem = nodeFilter(document.getElementById('input'));
      console.log('Filtered content:', elem.innerHTML);

      // This will NOT alter the clipboard in the stackoverflow sandbox,
      // but will work on your own page if you have the rights.
      navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
          'text/html': new Blob([elem.innerHTML], {
            type: 'text/html',
          }),
          'text/plain': new Blob([elem.innerText], {
            type: 'text/plain',
          }),
        }),
      ]);

      console.log('Rich text copied to clipboard');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    }
  }
)
<p id="input">
  A paragraph with a lot of text and a <a href="https://example.com/" data-example="small" class="main link" style="color:#0f0;"><span style="color:#F00;">l</span><span style="color:#0F0;">i</span><span style="color:#00F;">n</span>k</a> to something.
  <script>
    const a = Math.random();
  </script>
  <? processing instruction ?>
  <!-- A comment -->
</p>
<button id="btnCopy">Copy</button>



